# Schengen Visa Application for France through VFS Global

Tags: schengen, france, vfs-global

I applied for a Schengen visa for France along with my wife on 9th February, 2024, at 8:56 am through VFS Global, Hyderabad.  I got a mail on the same day that my application was sent to VFS Global for processing at 22:03 pm. Does that mean my visa application was rejected?

Here's the conversation thread over SMS:
[image: VFS Message Thread]

Comment: I don’t see anything here other than your application is being processed. What makes you think it has been rejected?

Comment: @Traveller it's possible that the messages at 22:03 imply that a decision has been reached (or maybe they don't); if they do, it's possible that the 13-hour period after the initial processing messages is too short for a positive decision (or maybe it isn't).  It's likely that nothing can be inferred from these messages, but it's also possible that someone who is familiar with the details of VFS's operations (and/or France's visa operations) in India could infer something meaningful from them.